# Why is my sda3 always almost full?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron with 2 drives: `sda`: SSD, 120 GB; `sdb`: Disk, 500 GB.

After `df -h`, I see `sda3` is 92% full and sometimes (like trying to add Whonix to VirtualBox), I get messages about disk being full, and sure enough, `sda3` has gone to, like, 98% or something.

I know this is the 3rd partition of the first, SSD drive from which the machine boots (from `sda1`), but *what is in this 3rd partition* and *how could I move it to `sdb`*?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           785M  9.7M  776M   2% /run
/dev/sda3        99G   86G  7.9G  92% /
tmpfs           3.9G   40M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       84M   84M     0 100% /snap/core/3604
/dev/loop0       84M   84M     0 100% /snap/core/3440
/dev/loop2       84M   84M     0 100% /snap/core/3247
/dev/loop4      232M  232M     0 100% /snap/vuze-vs/2
/dev/loop5      1.5M  1.5M     0 100% /snap/tldr-luk3yx/1
/dev/loop3      2.9M  2.9M     0 100% /snap/pulseaudio/9
/dev/sda1       596M   37M  560M   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs           785M   76K  785M   1% /run/user/1001
```

Comment: According to your screenshot, it's mounted to `/`, and it includes `/home`. You either have too much installed software, or too much stuff in `/home` probably. Moving it is realistically a reinstall. The easiest way out is to boot with a live distribution, move everything in `/home/` to a different partition, and mount it appropriately.

Comment: The '/' partition gets full because you've added apps to your system since install; though as you setup '/home' to use the same partition, its also being filled by anything you save in your '/home/*' too. 8GB allows no added apps, no upgrades to later-versions, so you need a larger '/' partition to make it livable.  Please don't use photos of text; copy & paste the text in your question!

Comment: Can you add the output of `df -h` to the question, just the text itself, not a link to the picture of a terminal window with the text.

Comment: According your your df screenshot, you're not even using your 500GB drive (/dev/sdb). You need to partition it and move your /home directory there: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving (I'd probably use ext4 instead of ext3 though).

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text. Instead, paste the text into your question, select the text, and press the `{}` button in the editor to format it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the files and see, and decide for yourself what you might want to move or erase. Use `baobab` / disk usage analyzer for a nice graphical overview (or `du` if you really like static terminals), as root to see all the "hiddden from your user" stuff:

```
sudo baobab /
```

You can move your /home (probably just about any folder if you wanted) to another drive, as Vanessa Deagan suggests with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving